# Calling a const property inside a Class in Laravel using a dynamic string

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class Constant in App\Utilities *See Below:*

```
<?php
 class Constant {
   const

        WEEK_1 = 'Week 1',
        WEEK_2 = 'Week 2';
}
?>
```

And I can echo Constant::WEEK_1 it gives me 'Week 1',

But what I want is to dynamically call constant week say

```
foreach([1,2] as $key => $num) {
   echo Constant::'WEEK_'.$num
}
```

And Im getting a parse error.

How to do this? Anyone? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic constant name in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995197/dynamic-constant-name-in-php)

Comment: @Uchiha I think its not a duplicate. The link you attached is not using Laravel. And my tweek was to include the namespace. Though both using constant define function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer my self by doing:

```
echo constant('App\Utilities\Constant::WEEK_'.$num);
```