# Access to a const using a variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Let me explain with a real example:

```
class Config{
 const DB_NAME = "FOO";
}

class ConfigLoader{
 public static function get($key) {
   return Config::$key;
 }
 public static function getTest() {
   return Config::DB_NAME;
 }
}

ConfigLoader::get("DB_NAME"); // return error: Access to undeclared static property

ConfigLoader::getTest(); // It's OK! return FOO
```

But i need to do something like ConfigLoader::get("DB_NAME) method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic constant name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995197/dynamic-constant-name-in-php)
See static property usage in second answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class
Using Reflection maybe useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ain't found a direct way to access constants of class. But by using reflection class it's possible.

```
class ConfigLoader
{
    public static function get($key)
    {
        return (new ReflectionClass('Config'))->getConstant('DB_NAME');
        // return (new ReflectionClass('Config'))->getConstants()['DB_NAME'];
    }

    public static function getTest()
    {
        return Config::DB_NAME;
    }
}


echo ConfigLoader::get('DB_NAME'); // return error: Access to undeclared static property
```

> **The [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) class reports information about a class.**
>   **[ReflectionClass::getConstant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstant.php) — Gets defined constant**
>   **[ReflectionClass::getConstants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) — Gets constants**

**Output**

```
FOO
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea9916c9c8d291e4b5830093ee21586545e34474).

Comment: I suggest to add namespace at the top of class `ConfigLoader`. Give it alias as `Config`. And check

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very useful for me